# Mongodb and querying that searching polygons that intersect a polygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

How to write a query in Mongodb that searches polygons that intersect a polygon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Geospatial intersection of two polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683931/mongodb-geospatial-intersection-of-two-polygon)

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-BoundsQueries) states that:

> Polygon searches are strictly limited to looking for points inside
>   polygons, polygon shapes in documents can't currently be indexed in MongoDB.
>   Blockquote

So it's not yet possible, I'm afraid.